# Get sum of array values based on date values of other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, date, reduce

So i have problem like this:

I have 2 arrays:

 one from mysql query that contains date when order have been created and total sum of it

```
const ordersData = [
0: {id: 1, data: '2021-11-23T00:00:00.000Z', price: 394}
1: {id: 2, data: '2021-11-23T00:00:00.000Z', price: 315.3}
2: {id: 3, data: '2021-11-23T00:00:00.000Z', price: 16445}
...
6: {id: 7, data: '2021-11-23T00:00:00.000Z', price: 200}
7: {id: 8, data: '2021-12-22T00:00:00.000Z', price: 618}

]
```

second is array is where i have monthly sum, month, first and last day of month

```
const pastMonthsData = [
   0: {
    month: "december",
    firstDay: Wed Dec 01 2021,
    lastDay: Fri Dec 31 2021,
    totalMonthSum: x
 },
   1: {
    month: "november",
    firstDay: Mon Nov 01 2021,
    lastDay: Tue Nov 30 2021,
    totalMonthSum: x
 }
]
```

I need to check if date from order array is in between date of pastMonthsData and add price to totalMonthSum.

So far i created func like this but it only works for december, for november there is no result.

```
pastMonthsData.forEach((el, i) => {
        el.totalMonthSum = ordersData.reduce((total, item) => {
          let itemDate = new Date(item.data);
          if(el.firstDay.getTime() < itemDate.getTime() && itemDate.getTime() < el.lastDay.getTime()) {
            return total + item.price
          } else {
            return 0
          }
        })
      });
```

Comment: Where is the real code that initializes `pastMonthsData`?

Comment: @jarmod it's a function that creates array of object based on previous months it's not something important here i think

Comment: The reason I asked was to make it easier for us to run your code and help you. As it stands, every single person who wants to help potentially has to modify your code to correct the variable initializations. You should always post standalone code that can be run, if possible. It's better for us, and therefore better for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two fixes:

1. initialize the accumulated total to zero
2. return the accumulated total, rather than zero, when a date is not in range

For example:

```
pastMonthsData.forEach((el, i) => {
  el.totalMonthSum = ordersData.reduce((total, item) => {
    let itemDate = new Date(item.data);
    if (el.firstDay.getTime() < itemDate.getTime() && itemDate.getTime() < el.lastDay.getTime()) {
      return total + item.price;
    } else {
      return total;
    }
  }, 0)
});
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to add initialize in question, returning total rather than zero helped me and now everything works. Thanks!